# Using qplot to make a dotplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, cran

I would like to make a wrapper for `qplot` that changes the default geom from `histogram` to `dotplot` if `x` is numeric and `y` is null. However I can't get `qplot` to work with `geom_dotplot`:

```
> x <- rnorm(100)
> qplot(x, geom="dotplot")
stat_bindot: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
Error in if (params$stackdir == "up") { : argument is of length zero
```

How can I use `qplot` to create this figure:

```
ggplot(,aes(x=x)) + geom_dotplot()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

qplot is missing a default aesthetics set for geom_dotplot. You could specify them manually:

```
qplot(x, geom = "dotplot",
      stackdir = "up", stackgroups = FALSE, binaxis = "x")
```

Plus binwidth.

Comment: Probably this counts as a bug, I would imagine.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but consider these two attempts that do not throw errors:

```
g <- qplot(x)
g + geom_dotplot()  # makes a weird hybrid dotplot and barplot
```

Or:

```
g <- qplot(x, stat="bindot")
g    # was expecting dots but got bars, go figure.
```